# Community Tip Calculator Issues

Tags: c#

So. I've been working on a tip calculator for a local business and i'm running into some issues.

Its supposed to first take 10% of the total tips and subtract it from the total tip amount (this is a bonus for people closing the store), take the remaining tip amount and divide it giving front workers 65% and back workers 35% then take the number of front workers who are closing, divide the 10% among the front workers who are closing and the back workers who are closing and give them their respective amounts as mentioned before (65% or 35%) ontop of the split 10% then spit the totals out into their respective boxes.

Its not spitting out the amounts. I've written the equations out several times on paper and implemented them but somehow they are quite clicking.

```
private void calcButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //define objects
    double tipAmount;
    double tipReduction;
    double tipDeduction;
    double frontWorkers;
    double backWorkers;
    double closeFrontWorkers;
    double closeBackWorkers;
    double frontWorkersUse;
    double backWorkersUse;
    double closeFrontWorkersUse;
    double closeBackWorkersUse;
    double frontPer;
    double backPer;
    double closeFrontPer;
    double closeBackPer;
    double tipDeductionPer;
    double totalCloseWorkers;
    double frontWorkersNew;
    double backWorkersNew;

    tipAmount = double.Parse(tipBox.Text);
    frontWorkers = double.Parse(frontWorkBox.Text);
    backWorkers = double.Parse(backWorkBox.Text);
    closeFrontWorkers = double.Parse(frontCloseWorkBox.Text);
    closeBackWorkers = double.Parse(backCloseWorkBox.Text);
    frontWorkersNew = frontWorkers + closeFrontWorkers;
    backWorkersNew = backWorkers + closeBackWorkers;

    tipReduction = tipAmount * .9;
    tipDeduction = tipAmount - tipReduction;
    totalCloseWorkers = closeFrontWorkers + closeBackWorkers;
    tipDeductionPer = tipDeduction / totalCloseWorkers;

    frontWorkersUse = tipReduction * .65;
    backWorkersUse = tipReduction * .35;
    closeFrontWorkersUse = (frontWorkersUse/frontWorkersNew);
    closeBackWorkersUse = (backWorkersUse/backWorkersNew);

    frontPer = frontWorkersUse / frontWorkersNew;
    backPer = backWorkersUse / backWorkersNew;
    closeFrontPer = (closeFrontWorkersUse / closeFrontWorkers) + tipDeduction;
    closeBackPer = (closeBackWorkersUse / closeBackWorkers) + tipDeduction;


    totalFrontWorkBox.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", frontPer);
    totalBackWorkBox.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", backPer);
    totalCloseWorkBoxFront.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", closeFrontPer);
    totalCloseWorkBoxBack.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", closeBackPer);
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I've removed all irrelevant code from your question, if you feel I've deleted something that is necessary to your exact issue then please feel free to re-add it. Also, just a small pointer to make your code a little cleaner... you don't need to define all variables at the top of your method, C# supports defining them inline as required

Comment: With `double` you'll be accumulating errors all over the place. Switch to `decimal` and see if results are any different.

Comment: You could use numericupdown instead of textboxes too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your (main) issue is in the logic.

I copied your code into Linqpad and changed it so that it wasn't relying on text boxes. Then I put some simple values in place of your numbers, and compared to what I'd expect. This showed that your error was with the closing workers' tip calculations, rather than the general tips. And the closing workers' tips were too big!

I then had a look at the relevant bits of your code and wondered why you were assigning the variable `tipDeductionPer` but never using its value - you're using `tipDeduction` and giving each of the closing staff the full amount!

What everyone else says in the comments is valid too. Your code could be a lot cleaner and easier to understand, and you'd find it easier to spot bugs. You could post on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) once you've fixed your bugs to get some pointers on how to improve it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm very new to C# and its kind of 3:30 in the morning.....I'll sleep and reflect on this post again. Thanks again.